# how to? if is_front = div class "front-content" else "content"

Tags: views

I have a view that displays the latest articles on the front page and it links to the full article. I want to force a div class to the front page to 70% so I tried to add these lines to both block.tpl and page.tpl and it doesn't take into account the condition, it just sets to front-content on both displays.

Here is the code:

```
<?php if (!$is_front): ?>
    <div class="front-content"><?php print render($page['content']); ?></div>
    <?php else: ?><div class="content"><?php print render($page['content']); ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a new class (and a div) you can simply target and override the layout for the front page in your style sheet with:

```
.front .content {
  width: 70%;
}
```

It's possibly you need to be more specific though, so you don't target all `.content` on the page. I don't know how you theme code looks, but it should be something like `.front #main .content`.

This assumes that your theme uses the default body classes in [html.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!html.tpl.php/7) for Drupal 7

```
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
```

Or [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/6) for Drupal 6.

```
<body class="<?php print $body_classes; ?>">
```

Cheers,

Comment: the issue with .content is that it affects both articles and the sidebar width, that's why I created 2 classes. 
How would I define .front if it's not in any output?

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: my html.tpl page is untouched d7 and basically the page has #body-wrap, .content .sidebar. I have been able to control the issue now but it generates another issue. the front articles needs a pager and as soon as I add it the sidebar gets pushed down. have a look at the site, I added the pager so you can see: http://groovymotion.com/blog/ thanks in advance!

Comment: That is an unrelated issue, but it seems you have missed to close a div somewhere.

Comment: thanks @enzipher it was the body-wrap tag! I also solved all issues, I found out that before .content there was one called region-content and I set it to 68% and let the content without any size. all is good now